# nested inline form set using extra_views and not for admin

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

I am trying to achieve a functionality, which is supported for admin forms using `nested_inline`.

In order to utilize something similar for public(non admin and the one being rendered using Custom Class Based View) form, I am using `extra_views`, which supports inlines but only at one depth level.

Below is the use case.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ProjectDetails(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)


class ProjectAddress(models.Model):
    address = models.textField()
    project_detail = models.ForeignKey(ProjectDetails)
```

A project can have multiple project details, Each project detail will have one address.

So, when the Model Project form renders it should be in below format.

```
ProjectForm

  ProjectDetailsForm

        ProjectAddressForm
```

This is achievable in admin using `nested_inline.admin's` `NestedStackedInline` &  `NestedModelAdmin`

Is there a way to achieve same in class based views(`CreateWithInlinesView`, `CreateWithInlinesView`) using `extra_views` or any some such ?

Please consider model only as an example.

I went through lot of links, but none of them seems to provide a native kind of way as nested_inline did for admin form. And, when tried a few work arounds(using inlineformset_factory), the ProjectDetailsForm was not rendered but only ProjectAddressForm was.

Any help or guidance to above problem would be really appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, not precisely. I have to create custom forms in default django way and render to client.